# Correct robots.txt structure? (Mediawiki)

Tags: mediawiki, robots.txt

I've been checking around in different sites robots.txt files and stumbled upon something I didn't expect at MediaWiki's robots.txt. From what I've read so far you would can write in a robots.txt file like below:

```
Disallow: foo
Noindex: bar
```

I then wonder if:

```
Disallow: /wiki/Category:Noindexed_pages
```

is a correct structure in a robots.txt file, or at least for mediawiki's part? Also wants to know if *Noindexed_pages* can be anything or if it is static.

The last code was taken from a wikipedia article of [mediawiki's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Robots.txt) robots.txt.

Comment: What exactly made you wonder? The slash at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/wiki/Category:Noindexed_pages` is a MediaWiki [category page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories) that links to pages that should not be indexed. The rule is probably there to prevent the category itself from propping up in search results when the search term is part of the title of a noindexed page.